# Remaining two rows get skipped in for-loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I am programming a maintenaince thing for tournaments. Players are divided into "leagues". At the end, the first player of league x gets to play against the losers of league y. Winner of league y meets loser of league z etc. Then this rule gets repeated fot the numbers 2 and second lasts of the next league, 3rds and 3rd lasts of next league and so on. The number of leagues varies every time. Everything works really fine until it comes to the last two remaining players, let's say the middle player of league x don't get connected to the middle player of league y. 
I found a way to work around this glitch but I'd rather have it working like it should.

This is my code: (khzz is the total amount of players without regarding leagues). Anybody sees what's wrong? Thanks!

```
for ($doen=0; $doen<=$hkzz; $doen++) {


            $unid2 = "" . $doen . "-" . rand(1600,20000) . "";


            $koppelpak = $conn->query ("SELECT * FROM poules WHERE poule='$startmet' AND amsyst='' ORDER BY ABS(ptn) DESC, karma DESC LIMIT 1");
            //$kppk = mysqli_fetch_assoc($koppelpak);
            while ($kppk = $koppelpak->fetch_array()) {

            $conn->query("UPDATE poules SET amsyst='$unid2' WHERE koppel='$kppk[koppel]' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));                

            echo "koppel " . $kppk['koppel'] . " uit poule " . $startmet . " tegen "; 

                $koppelpak2 = $conn->query ("SELECT * FROM poules WHERE poule='$volgende' AND amsyst='' ORDER BY ABS(ptn) ASC, karma ASC LIMIT 1");
                while ($kppk2 = $koppelpak2->fetch_array()) {

                    $conn->query("UPDATE poules SET amsyst='$unid2' WHERE koppel='$kppk2[koppel]' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                echo "koppel " . $kppk2['koppel'] . " uit poule " . $volgende . "<br />";

                }

            $startmet = $startmet + 1;
            $werk = $werk + 1;
            if ($startmet>$hoep) { $startmet="1"; }
            $volgende = $volgende + 1;
            if ($volgende>$hoep) { $volgende="1"; }

            //$volgen = $volgen + 1;

            } // while
            } // for
```

Comment: I learned to code from books so I'm no pro (which probably shows) - what's wrong with the code?

Comment: ... I just told you what's wrong. ???

Comment: You're running queries but no execute also..

Comment: OK thanks for the help already but sorry, I'm not totally familiar with all terminology, I use php for hobby projects only. I don't know how the "indentation is messed up" or "it's full of SQL injection bugs".
The page on which this code is used has lots more of code which works fine.
The whole thing works very fine except for this bug. I'm not asking to program it for me but it'd be a great help if anyone pointed out how it should be done. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I found it. There was no error in the code, I needed to use another for-loop. Problem solved.